# Using sysctl interface from kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to access tcp_pacing_ss_ratio defined in tcp_input.c from a kernel module. The variable can be modified using the sysctl command in user space.
It is however not exported and cannot be referenced directly from the module.

What is the simplest way to access a sysctl entry from a kernel module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`sysctl(2)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html):

> use of this system call has
>          long been discouraged, and it is so unloved that it is likely to
>          disappear in a future kernel version.  Since Linux 2.6.24, uses of
>          this system call result in warnings in the kernel log.  Remove it
>          from your programs now; **use the /proc/sys interface instead**.

This would be `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_pacing_ss_ratio` in your case, which you can write with `kernel_write`. Check out [`sysctl(2)`'s implementation for example usage](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14/source/kernel/sysctl_binary.c#L973).

Comment: I have tried filp_open + kernel_write and vfs_write. Both results in kernel panic.
My understanding is that the variable is part of a red-black tree located at init_net.sysctls. I cant seem to find any function for doing lookup. How does #include <net/net_namespace.h> help me?

Comment: The `sysctl(2)` system call itself uses `kernel_write`, so you probably doing something wrong... If you include the header, you should be able to get/set `init_net.ipv4.sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio` directly. I am inclined to think that would be "ok", because the procfs helpers seem to do just that. Proper way, I think, is `kernel_write` though.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, I will have another look later. Could you please point me to the functions for setting init_net.ipv4.sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio, I cant seem to find them.

Comment: It's a plain `int`. You _could_ just use it as you would use any normal variable (`init_net.ipv4.sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio = 200`).

Comment: error: ‘struct netns_ipv4’ has no member named ‘sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio’; did you mean ‘sysctl_tcp_ecn_fallback’?   It is added to init_net's structure in a call to register_net_sysctl in sysctl_net_ipv4.c.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I meant `sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio`.

Comment: The problem is that it is undefined from the view of the kernel module. So writing sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio = 400; results in; WARNING: "sysctl_tcp_pacing_ss_ratio" undefined! Nevertheless, I will retry writing directly to /proc/sys using the sysctl implementation as a reference later today.

Comment: Overlooked that. Removed the suggestion.

Comment: I finally got it to work by opening "sys/net/ipv4/tcp_pacing_ss_ratio" using file_open_root, and writing using vfs_write. Thank you for the suggestion to write directly to the file.

Comment: @FormerNcp, which is an ugly hack. Cleaner way is to make it exported or go through code and understand why it's not and what other possibilities.

Comment: I agree. This was done purely for educational purposes. It does not make sens for multiple TCP CC modules to modify these variables concurrently.